# Configure Hibernate models discovery in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

I want to configure Spring with Hibernate 5 and JNDI using this code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextDatasource {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.database.models");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() throws NamingException {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
          "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
          "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() 
      throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em 
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:/global/production_gateway");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

But when I deploy the code I get error. Looks like I have to add another XML configuration file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
```

Hibernate models are located in a remote jar under Java package `org.database.models` How I can map them using Java code?

Answer (score 1):

May you need to add dependencies to your pom file, if you use maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent hibernate persistence.xml usage, you must define on LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean the packages to scan entity from.

```
emf.setPackagesToScan(myPackagesToScan);
```

Comment: I added package but I got Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either